# IOS : How to get song id using echonest Api

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, echonest

I want to make app like shazam in IOS using echonest Api.
I have referred document of echonest and I found that They are not provided song identification Api ”https://developer.echonest.com/forums/thread/3650”

#### 1. Is there any Api for music identification?

or

#### 2. How can I identify song using echonest Api?

Please  share your answer

Thanks for advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

As it says in the link you used, Echonest is deprecating their song identification capabilities on their API starting January 5, 2015. So to answer your 2nd question first... you can't use their APIs anymore.

As for your 1st question, that's a fairly broad question and loaded with opinion (two things that stack overflow frowns upon). But I'll try my best.

[Mooma.sh](http://www.mooma.sh/api.html) was mentioned as an alternative song identification service further down the page in the link that you posted. However, they ALSO are shutting down their public API due to server load. They provided steps for you to set up and start your own server, [here](http://www.mooma.sh/api.html).

[Gracenote](https://developer.gracenote.com/music-platforms) could be another possible alternative. I have tried neither of these APIs, but if you do some quick googling you should be able to find a service that best fits your needs.

Good luck!

Comment: :Thanks for your suggestion,as you suggested Moooma.sh & Gracenote but it is not useful for me.Could you suggest me any another Api which is usefull for me.

Comment: I'm confused, what is it about them that do not make them useful?